# Creating a folder to call Scripts from

Tags: c#

I have a C# project that has an install file once it's built (basically installing the file installs the application which is an exe and runs as a backround task on windows). I have installed python.net and I am trying to create a folder inside the application to which the python scripts will be saved and will be called from.

I am very new to C# and I want to know what's the best way to do this. Should I create a pre-build task to create a new directory or should I simply create a new folder inside the project?

Any kind of help will be appreciated as I am pretty lost.

Comment: Do you want those scripts to be editable? Mind that this will create a possible attack vector. A malicious user could inject literally any code...

Comment: @Fildor I do not want it to be editable. I just need to save my scripts in that folder and call them when necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should create a folder in the project, easiest using the right click Add on the project icon. And then in the lower right corner (if you are using visual studio) in the Properties panel make sure to select **Always copy** in the Copy to Output Directory row.
[image]

Comment: Will this folder exist when I install the application using an install script?

Comment: I also do not see the 2 properties for a folder, just see "Name". I added a "New Solution Folder"

Comment: The folder does not have the properties, sorry. But the actual files will have the properties and you need to set those to Copy Always. If you are using Microsoft tools to generate the install exe, then it should copy the folder with the files in the install directory.